# iOSのKeychain Serviceについて

Tags: ios, swift4

keychainを使った実装を行おうとしてて、一つ気になったことがあったので質問させていただきました。

Keychain Serviceに格納できる型について質問なんですが、String型とData型以外の型は、そのまま格納できず工夫（Data型などに一旦変換する）をしないといけないんでしょうか。

単純な質問で恐れ入りますが、何卒ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Keychain Serviceに格納できる型について質問なんですが、String型とData型以外の型は、そのまま格納できず工夫（Data型などに一旦変換する）をしないといけないんでしょうか。

その通りです。もっと正確にいうと、Keychain ServiceのAPIはCFData型（＝Data/NSData）しか受け付けないため、StringさえもData型に変換して格納する必要があります。